# Ordering collections and relational collections laravel

Tags: php, sorting, laravel-5

I have the following laravel query

```
    $user = $this->user; //current user (dispatcher)

    //obtain list of dispatchers,trucks,deliveries,drivers,trailers
    $dispatchers = $this->instance->user()->where('active', 1)->with(['truck.delivery' => function($query) use ($week_array) {
                            $query->where('delivery_date', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::parse($week_array[1]['date'])->toDateTimeString())->whereNotNull('driver_id')
                            ->orderBy('delivery_date');
                        }])->with(['truck.trailer', 'truck.driver', 'truck.driver2', 'truck.trailer.trailerType'])->get()
                    ->sortBy('name')->sortBy(function ($item) use ($user) {
        return $item->id == $user->id ? 1 . $item->name : 2 . $item->name;
    });
```

My goal is to have CURRENT user to be the first item in the collection, and then, I want to have this collection ordered alphabetically by the user name.

In addition, this is where I am having a problem, I need to sort each user's drivers (a subset of a subset) alphabetically.

Sort level 1 for the whole collection: `$user fist, and then by $dispatchers->name`

Sort level 2 for each item in the collection: `$dispatchers->truck->driver->first-name`

I was able to create a sort for Level 1 (when current user is always comes on top), but I am unable to sort a collection for each user.

The final result should be like (users ordered and their trucks collections ordered by driver names in driver collection)

```
CURRENT USER (not matter the name)
 Truck 50
  Driver AA
 Truck 45
  Driver BB
 Truck 56
  Driver CC

USER A
 Truck 10
  Driver A
 Truck 6
  Driver B
 Truck 20
  Driver C

USER B
 Truck 2
  Driver D
 Truck 3
  Driver E
 Truck 1
  Driver F

USER C
 Truck 30
  Driver G
 Truck 35
  Driver H
 Truck 13
  Driver Z
```

etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = $this->user; //current user (dispatcher)

//obtain list of dispatchers,trucks,deliveries,drivers,trailers
$dispatchers = $this->instance->user()->where('active', 1)
    ->with([
        'truck' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['trucks.*']);
            $query->join('drivers', 'trucks.id', '=', 'drivers.truck_id');
            $query->oldest('drivers.name');
        },
        'truck.delivery' => function($query) use ($week_array) {
            $query
                ->where('delivery_date', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::parse($week_array[1]['date'])->toDateTimeString())
                ->whereNotNull('driver_id')
                ->orderBy('delivery_date');
    }])
    ->with(['truck.trailer', 'truck.driver', 'truck.driver2', 'truck.trailer.trailerType'])->get()
    ->sortBy('name')->sortBy(function ($item) use ($user) {
        return $item->id == $user->id ? 1 . $item->name : 2 . $item->name;
    });
```

It works for me, but not sure in your case.